# How can I generate a release version of a c++ program with python script

Tags: python, c++

I have write a simple C++ program which calls a python script in it.(target platform is windows)

I want to create a release version to run on machine without python installed.

But I can not specific which modules should be included in the release package.

Is there any tools to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can first use [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) or [pyinstaller](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller) to convert the python script to exe. Then call the exe in the C++ program.

Comment: I have some code in c++ and python is just a part of my program. Furthermore I will call functions in python so it seems not a perfect way.Yet, it maybe a good idea to create a exe file with cx_freeze and I'll got all the required modules in the build folder. I can remove the exe file generated by cx_freeze and then move my exe there.

Comment: Can' t you create one exe for python script and call that exe in your c++?

Comment: Of course I can, but it is not the best way, right?